# How to create negative Corner Radius

Tags: wpf, border, progress

So i have this `Progress-Bar` and on its right side simple `Border` that inside this `Border` i want to put `Label` (The `Progress-Bar`is on the left side):

[image]

And here after this 2 `Progress-Bar` is with value of `100%`:

[image]

As you can see i can see the `Progress-Bar` `Corner Radius` and i want my `Border` left side will be with negative `Corner Radius`

My `Progress-Bar` style:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ProgressBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                    <Grid MinHeight="14" MinWidth="200">
                        <Border Name="PART_Track"
                                CornerRadius="5,0,0,5"
                                Background="{DynamicResource ProgressBarBackgroundColor}"
                                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ProgressBarBackgroundColor}"
                                BorderThickness="0" />
                        <Border Name="PART_Indicator"
                                CornerRadius="8" 
                                Background="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFillBackgroundColor}"
                                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFillBackgroundColor}" 
                                BorderThickness="0" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

#### XAML

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ProgressBar Name="progressBar"
                 Height="20"
                 Width="700"
                 Minimum="0"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Maximum="100"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Value="{Binding Progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                                                                                                                                             
                 Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ProgressBar}}"
                 Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    <Border Width="40"
            Height="19"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            CornerRadius="0,5,5,0"
            Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF343D46" Opacity="0.4"/>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>

**UPDATE**
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but the code you've posted doesn't match the screen shots. I think I understand what you're trying to do, but post some sample code that actually matches your problem and you'll probably have better luck at getting a response.

Comment: This is my code

Answer (score 3):

In essence what you want to do is when you have a progress bar value of 100 you want to apply a different template too the one you have when you are just displaying the progress bar. Use the following XAML:

You can see that in the trigger template - the corner radius property has been set too zero for the correct corners of the progress bar track.

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type ProgressBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                    <Grid MinHeight="14" MinWidth="200">
                        <Border Name="PART_Track"
                                CornerRadius="5,0,0,5"
                                Background="{DynamicResource ProgressBarBackgroundColor}"
                                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ProgressBarBackgroundColor}"
                                BorderThickness="0" />
                        <Border Name="PART_Indicator"
                                CornerRadius="5"
                                Background="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFillBackgroundColor}"
                                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFillBackgroundColor}"
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Value" Value="100">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                            <Grid MinHeight="14" MinWidth="200">
                                <Border Name="PART_Track"
                                        CornerRadius="5,0,0,5"
                                        Background="{DynamicResource ProgressBarBackgroundColor}"
                                        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ProgressBarBackgroundColor}"
                                        BorderThickness="0" />
                                <Border Name="PART_Indicator"
                                        CornerRadius="5,0,0,5"
                                        Background="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFillBackgroundColor}"
                                        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFillBackgroundColor}"
                                        BorderThickness="0"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

This will result in the following behaviour:

[image]

Comment: Please see my update, what you did with the Progress-Bar is fine but on the right side i want Border with rounded corners but this time opposite

Comment: What I have done in situations like that is placed the progressbar overlaying the label slightly. Instead of placing the bar inside a stackpanel put it in a grid and overlap the progress bar over the label.

Comment: Sorry but i did not understand your method, can i have simple code example ?